# Find next N rows when condition is TRUE

Tags: r, data.table

How can I get the row when condition is TRUE and N rows following it? If condition is TRUE in any of the N rows, restart the count. Also do this for each group.

```
dt = data.table(a = rep(c("a","b","c"), each = 5), b = 1:15)
dt[, condition := b%%4 == 0]
> dt
    a  b condition **desiredOutcome**
 1: a  1     FALSE           FALSE
 2: a  2     FALSE           FALSE
 3: a  3     FALSE           FALSE
 4: a  4      TRUE            TRUE
 5: a  5     FALSE            TRUE
 6: b  6     FALSE           FALSE
 7: b  7     FALSE           FALSE
 8: b  8      TRUE            TRUE
 9: b  9     FALSE            TRUE
10: b 10     FALSE            TRUE
11: c 11     FALSE           FALSE
12: c 12      TRUE            TRUE
13: c 13     FALSE            TRUE
14: c 14     FALSE            TRUE
15: c 15     FALSE           FALSE
```

The `desiredOutcome` is based on `N=2` and group by column `a`. What's the best way to get this?

Comment: `dt[, shift(condition, 0:N), by = a]` nearly works, except it's very hard to row sum the output of shift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the way to sum up the results of `shift`, ie a list of vectors.

`dt[, desiredOutcome := Reduce('+', shift(con, 0:2, fill = 0)), by = a]`

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
 dt[dt[, {i1 <- which(condition); .I[i1:pmin((i1+2), .N)]} , a]$V1,
     desiredOutcome:= TRUE][is.na(desiredOutcome), desiredOutcome := FALSE][]
# a  b condition desiredOutcome
# 1: a  1     FALSE          FALSE
# 2: a  2     FALSE          FALSE
# 3: a  3     FALSE          FALSE
# 4: a  4      TRUE           TRUE
# 5: a  5     FALSE           TRUE
# 6: b  6     FALSE          FALSE
# 7: b  7     FALSE          FALSE
# 8: b  8      TRUE           TRUE
# 9: b  9     FALSE           TRUE
#10: b 10     FALSE           TRUE
#11: c 11     FALSE          FALSE
#12: c 12      TRUE           TRUE
#13: c 13     FALSE           TRUE
#14: c 14     FALSE           TRUE
#15: c 15     FALSE          FALSE
```

Comment: Sorry, my choice of example might have been misleading. I don't want TRUE until the end, but next N rows. I have modified the example.

Comment: Thanks! But if there are two rows that satisfy the condition in one group, ie `which(condition)` returns a vector, this fails

Comment: @jf328  This solution is based on the example you provided.